# I have a JTextArea that needs bottom margin

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea with margins that work for the top, left, and right but not for the bottom. When the caret gets to the bottom, it just keeps going.

Here is my code:

```
    frame = new JFrame("");
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setMargin(new Insets(10, 50, 50, 560));
```

Comment: Put the `JTextArea` in `JScrollPane` - it's has an unconstrained height (meaning it can overflow the specified height)

Comment: just posted what happened when i used a JScrollPane.

Comment: also i do not want the caret to continue forward i want it to stop altogether when it reaches the bottom margin.

Comment: Then you're asking for something that the API doesn't support natively, nor which I think is going to be easily implementable.  My first thought is to use a `DocumentFilter` which can limit both the number of characters and number of lines, but this doesn't take into account the fact that different systems render fonts differently